# Clob to String: BufferedReader vs getSubString()?

Tags: java, jdbc, clob

I am writing  a Java program to read clob columns from a database containing XML data and do some processing.

I need to use Regex on this XML content, so converting to string is a useful approach for me, and I am sure the length of the clob will not exceed the capacity of a String  for the operational purposes. As of now, the shortest and longest CLOBs from approx. *4000* total entries in the DB are **2000** chars and **18000** chars respectively.

My question is: With this sort of a max length (say 20k chars), which of the 2 following approaches is recommended and why?

**Approach 1:**  Method `getSubString()` on Clob, simpler to use:

```
// cXML is the Clob object   
String sXML = cXML.getSubString(1, (int)cXML.length());
```

**Approach 2:**  Use `BufferedReader` and `StringBuilder` in a method (Better performance?):

```
private String ClobToString(Clob data)
throws Exception
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder exDtl = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Reader reader = data.getCharacterStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        exDtl.append(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        exDtl.append(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (exDtl.length() > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(exDtl.toString());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
} // End Method ClobToString
```

I have read in some websites/forums that **Approach 2** is better in terms of performance, so I am trying to understand:

1. At what threshold of Clob length does it become advisable to use **Approach 2** instead of **Approach 1**?
2. Are neither of these approaches recommended, and if so what would be a third approach?
    (I was looking to avoid 3rd party libraries like StreamFlyer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of approach 2 is flawed and since the data is not processed in a streaming fashion anyway, use approach 1. Approach 1 will call the driver's implementation of approach 2 which is probably more accurate and could look something like this:

```
public static String getString(Clob data) throws SQLException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] cbuf = new char[8192];
    int l = 0;
    try (Reader r = data.getCharacterStream()) {
        while ((l = r.read(cbuf)) > -1) {
            sb.append(cbuf, 0, l);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new SQLException("Unable to read character stream from Clob.", ioe);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I don't think it will make any difference in performance.

Comment: Sorry, I did not fully understand why you considered the implementation of the approach 2 I provided as non-streaming processing. Your code (for the hypothetical driver implementation) seems similar except:  

1. It uses a char array instead of a String to store the buffer  
2. It uses a fixed length (8192 chars) for the buffer whereas mine uses a line by line buffering  
- Can you explain a bit more?  
Nevertheless, it's good to know that the driver implementation can take care of this, I was hoping to go with the much simpler approach 1 :)

Comment: With non streaming processing I was referring to "Regex on this XML content" - you are not matching a regex on a stream of XML data but on a complete in-memory String of XML data. The line by line buffering assumes all line-breaks are always '\n' but that is not always the case. It also adds nothing: the BufferedReader has to search for the line-breaks but nothing is done with them. The reader is not closed in a finally block (which might leave it open). And buffering a buffer (the reader returned by `getCharacterStream()` is probably also buffered) is bad for performance.